# Inner joins on junction objects

Tags: soql

I'd like to do an inner join on 2 junction objects, and I can't get the syntax right. I want an inner join on ContactRole (which is related to opportunities and contacts), and Opportunity__c that is related to Opporunity and a custom Object (both of these are MDR). I want to join them on Account Id.

Here's what I think the SQL join should look like:

```
Select o.Role, o.OpportunityId, o.Opportunity.name, opportunity.accountId, o.Id, o.ContactId , o.contact.name, opp.id, opp.name
From OpportunityContactRole o
join Opportunity__c opp
on opportunity.accountid = opp.Opportunity__r.accountId
```

I can't get the soql to line up. Where the editor doesn't inderstand the relationship: `Invalid_type= from opportunity__c opp. Didn't understand the relationship 'Opportunity__c" in FROM part of query call....`

Here's the SOQL I'm trying:

```
Select o.Role, o.OpportunityId, o.Opportunity.name, opportunity.accountId, o.Id, o.ContactId , o.contact.name,  
    (       select opp.id, opp.name 
    from Opportunity__c opp
    where opp.Opportunity__r.accountId = '00130000000EY9D'
    )

From OpportunityContactRole o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the correct relationship name for your object.  You need to fix that in order to get it to work.

What IDE to you use?  If you use Eclipse, you can open up your project schema then:

Find the object you desire.  Expand child relationships, then find the one that you want.  Select a field from that and it will automatically build the query for you.

Comment: i'll double check. i'm joining on the accountId of the opportunity on the inner join though.

Comment: @nivyaj Thats not what I'm talking about.  Talking about **FROM Opportunity__c** is wrong.

Comment: dphil is right - there can't be a field called Opportunity__c on OpportunityContactRole since you can't create custom fields on that object right now...